# Can JMX operations take interfaces as parameters?

Tags: java, jmx, mbeans

I'm having problems with an `MBean` that takes a `Map<String, Object>` as a parameter. If I try to execute it via JMX using a proxy object, I get an Exception:

```
Caused by: javax.management.ReflectionException
    at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:231)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:668)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to find operation updateProperties(java.util.HashMap)
```

It appears that it attempts to use the actual implementation class rather than the interface, and doesn't check if this is a child of the required interface. The same thing happens for extended classes (for example declare `HashMap`, pass in `LinkedHashMap`). Does this mean it's impossible to use an interface for such methods? At the moment I'm getting around it by changing the method signature to accept a `HashMap`, but it seems odd that I wouldn't be able to use interfaces (or extended classes) in my `MBeans`.

Edit: The proxy object is being created by an in-house utility class called `JmxInvocationHandler`. The (hopefully) relevant parts of it are as follows:

```
public class JmxInvocationHandler implements InvocationHandler
{
    ...
    public static <T> T createMBean(final Class<T> iface, SFSTestProperties properties, String mbean, int shHostID)
    {
        T newProxyInstance = (T) Proxy.newProxyInstance(iface.getClassLoader(), new Class[] { iface }, (InvocationHandler) new JmxInvocationHandler(properties, mbean, shHostID));
        return newProxyInstance;
    }
    ...
    private JmxInvocationHandler(SFSTestProperties properties, String mbean, int shHostID)
    {
        this.mbeanName = mbean + MBEAN_SUFFIX + shHostID;
        msConfig = new MsConfiguration(properties.getHost(0), properties.getMSAdminPort(), properties.getMSUser(), properties.getMSPassword());
    }
    ...
    public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args) throws Throwable
    {
        if (management == null)
        {
            management = ManagementClientStore.getInstance().getManagementClient(msConfig.getHost(),
                    msConfig.getAdminPort(), msConfig.getUser(), msConfig.getPassword(), false);
        }

        final Object result =  management.methodCall(mbeanName, method.getName(), args ==  null?  new Object[] {} : args);
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Thor;  Can you provide the code which creates your proxy object ?

Comment: I'm using an in-house utility class and frankly I'm not sure I can really work out what's going on in it (it's doing loads of additional things relating to security and isn't the best written piece of code I've ever seen), but I'll try to extract the important bits and add them to the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it. JMX invocations sometimes make cannon-fodder of the best intended utility classes .... :)

This guy, I suspect, is a problem:

```
public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args) throws Throwable
    {
        if (management == null)
        {
            management = ManagementClientStore.getInstance().getManagementClient(msConfig.getHost(),
                    msConfig.getAdminPort(), msConfig.getUser(), msConfig.getPassword(), false);
        }

        final Object result =  management.methodCall(mbeanName, method.getName(), args ==  null?  new Object[] {} : args);
        return result;
    }
```

because the MBean's operation signature (which cares not a whit about inheritance) is determined from the classes of the passed arguments. Since you cannot pass an actual concrete object for which `getClass()` will return `java.util.Map`, you will never make a match using the direct types of the arguments themselves. (Similar problems occur with primitives for the same reason).

See this [blog post](http://seeallhearall.blogspot.com/2012/01/groovymx-groovy-jmx-client.html) starting with the paragraph opening with "*One of the tricky parts of making MetaMBean"*, as it explains this problem (or the problem I think you're having) in a bit more detail, but the [invoke](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/management/MBeanServer.html#invoke%28javax.management.ObjectName,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D%29) method of the [MBeanServer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/management/MBeanServer.html)[Connection] is:

```
invoke(ObjectName name, String operationName, Object[] params, String[] signature)
```

The first 2 and the last arguments are navigational in that they specify exactly which operation amongst all the ops published in the server should be invoked. The best way to sidestep this issue is to avoid having to "guess" the signature and only rely on the ObjectName and the operation name, which in turn can be done by interrogating (and possibly caching) the [MBeanInfo](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/management/MBeanInfo.html) and [MBeanOperationInfo](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/management/MBeanOperationInfo.html)s of the target MBean. The MBeanOperationInfos will provide you the signature so you don't have to guess.

If this is indeed your issue, there's a couple of ways you can address it:

1. If the MBean's operation names are unique (i.e. there's no overloading) then you can just use the op name to retrieve the MBeanInfo.
2. If the MBean's operation is overloaded (i.e. there are multiple operations with the same name but different parameters)... but they all have different parameter counts, then you can easilly determine the correct signature by iterating all the matching op names in the MBeanOperationInfos and matching by param count.
3. If #1 and #2 do not apply.... then it's tricky and I would re-evaluate the method signatures of your MBean's code.
4. If #1 and #2 do not apply and #3 will not comply, take a look at this class in [Gmx](https://github.com/nickman/GroovyMX#readme) called [MetaMBean](https://github.com/nickman/GroovyMX/blob/master/gmx/src/main/java/org/helios/gmx/MetaMBean.java). In the latest revision, it uses Groovy to create a compiled runtime interface using the MBean's MBeanInfo to make inheritance (and autoboxing) work in method invocation. The same method could be implemented in JavaScript (which has the virtue of being built into Java 6+) or several other JVM scripting languages. Alternatively, look at the [previous version](https://github.com/nickman/GroovyMX/blob/6f6c1fe875216a85786e8d0b7d58a7f03522e70c/gmx/src/main/java/org/helios/gmx/Gmx.java) which attempted to pattern match against known operation signatures (and worked pretty well actually, but since I was working with Groovy anyways......)

I hope this is helpful. If this turns out not to be the root cause, then forget I said anything....

Comment: A very interesting and well thought out answer. Thanks. It'll be difficult for me to try it out right now because this class is in a different project and because I've been given a priority issue to deal with. For now I'll up-vote your answer because it seems to me it's likely correct, and I'll get back to you on whether or not I could fix it this way once I have the opportunity. Thanks a lot.